# Cannot get jQuery resizable to work: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, resize

Here is my simple code to try and test if jQuery resizable is working. I use other jQuery components just fine using the google.load, and I've tried swapping out the google.load for a local version with no difference. I've tested in 3 browsers, I've copied code from several demo/tutorial sites (where it works find on their site).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=blahblah_obviously changed_blahblah-blahblah_blah_blahblahblah"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.1");</script>
<style type="text/css">
   #resizable { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: silver; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#resizable").resizable();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>  
 <div id="resizable"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't get any error messages. I'm at my wit's end. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't even this simple case work?

UPDATE: the jQuery UI libraries are included by the line google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.1");

Comment: I hate jQuery and their sketchy examples ! It's like here ya go, you're lucky if you can figure this one out :P

Answer (score 46, accepted):

jQuery UI is working fine in your sample, the issue you have is because you don't have any CSS Theme included in your [last test](http://www.bcsfanpoll.com/test/test.php), and the "resizable handle" icon is not shown.

Add your [own theme](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) or the default one:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

See your sample [here](http://jsbin.com/emudi).

Answer (score 11):

All CSS you need to get working jquery ui .resizable():
 (don't forget to save image to local)

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png)/*{iconsContent}*/; }
.ui-resizable { position: relative;}
.ui-resizable-handle { position: absolute;font-size: 0.1px;z-index: 99999; display: block;}
.ui-resizable-disabled .ui-resizable-handle, .ui-resizable-autohide .ui-resizable-handle { display: none; }
.ui-resizable-n { cursor: n-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; top: -5px; left: 0px; }
.ui-resizable-s { cursor: s-resize; height: 7px; width: 100%; bottom: -5px; left: 0px; }
.ui-resizable-e { cursor: e-resize; width: 7px; right: -5px; top: 0px; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-w { cursor: w-resize; width: 7px; left: -5px; top: 0px; height: 100%; }
.ui-resizable-se { cursor: se-resize; width: 12px; height: 12px; right: 1px; bottom: 1px; }
.ui-resizable-sw { cursor: sw-resize; width: 9px; height: 9px; left: -5px; bottom: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-nw { cursor: nw-resize; width: 9px; height: 9px; left: -5px; top: -5px; }
.ui-resizable-ne { cursor: ne-resize; width: 9px; height: 9px; right: -5px; top: -5px;}
.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se { background-position: -64px -224px; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable();
  });
});
</script>
```

It's worth noting that google.load() is an async call and you won't be able to call the jQuery functions until they're loaded hence the callback.

Ok, had a look at your example and you've got a few problems:

1. This is the biggest: you have no jQuery UI stylesheet;
2. You're double including jQuery, jQuery UI and SWFObject from both Google and locally;
3. The last div inside your resizable div is blocking resizing. Not sure exactly why but I commented it out and it works fine; and
4. You don't need an API key for Google's AJAX Libraries API. This odesn't cause a problem. It's just FYI.

Working version of yours:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.1");
google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#resizable").resizable();
  });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
  #resizable { width: 100px; height: 100px; background: silver; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resizable">
  <div style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
  <div style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
  <!--<div unselectable="on" style="z-index: 1001; -moz-user-select: none;" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se"></div>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work. To prove I tried it and this isn't working for me, goto: http://www.bcsfanpoll.com/test/test.php

Comment: Adding the stylesheet link solved it. I don't see how I'm including the libraries twice? That last div is being added by jQuery (or Firefox), it's not part of my base code. The `<div id="resizable"></div>` is what is part of my code, nothing inside. Thanks for the no-API tip.